# SQL JSON DATA FILTER

Tags: python, mysql, sql

I have a table with a column named "data", it stores json data in form of a string like,

```
id , data

1 {'field1': '123432', 'field2': 'TEST', 'field3': '', 'field4': 'JAMES'}

2 {'field1': '123412', 'field2': 'TEST 2', 'field3': 'TEST', 'field4': 'TESTER'}
```

what is the best way to select all rows where "field3" of column "data" is not empty?

**TEST QUERY**

```
CREATE TABLE my_test(id INT,data TextField  );

insert into my_test values
(1,"{'field1': '123432', 'field2':'TEST'}"),
(2,"{'field1': '322345', 'field2':'TEST 2'}");
```

Thank you.

Comment: You can use [JSON_EXTRACT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json.html#json-paths)

Comment: Shown values are **NOT** valid JSON values from MySQL looking point.

Comment: incases like that, what should one do? @Akina

Comment: Please run the following `SHOW CREATE TABLE your_table_name;` and update [into your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/70854993/edit). Also, include the query you use to insert the data into the table.

Comment: @FanoFN Query updated

Comment: One more thing @kayodeolayiwola , please check your MySQL version by running `SELECT version();`, thanks. By the way, did you insert the data manually or you generate the insert using code (python code etc.)? I mean, how did you generate the `INSERT` query?

Answer (score 0):

If your data are correct json format maybe something like this can help:

```
select JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.field3'))
from test_tbl
where  JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.field3')) !='' ;





CREATE TABLE test_tbl(
id INT,
data json  );

insert into test_tbl values
(1,'{"field1": "123432", "field2":"TEST", "field3": "", "field4": "JAMES"}'),
(2,'{"field1": "123432", "field2":"TEST", "field3": "TEST", "field4": "JAMES"}');
```

> Result:
>
> ```
> JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(data, '$.field3'))
> TEST
> ```

[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=05eb26bdb1a78a90e52b192d78b0866f)

Comment: in my situation, my data are not valid mysql json, what can I do then?

Answer (score 0):

The way your data being stored does appear to look like `JSON` but unfortunately it's not a valid one. The single-quote should be double-quote instead. Depending on your MySQL version, you can verify whether the `JSON` data is valid or not by using [JSON_VALID](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/json-attribute-functions.html#function_json-valid) function:

```
SELECT *,
       JSON_VALID(data) AS check_if_json_data_is_valid
FROM my_test;
```

This is the result you'll get (with your exact data sample)

| id | data | check_if_json_data_is_valid |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {'field1': '123432', 'field2':'TEST', 'field3': ''} | 0 |
| 2 | {'field1': '322345', 'field2':'TEST 2', 'field3': 'TEST'} | 0 |

As you can see, `check_if_json_data_is_valid` returns `0`(zero) means that it's not valid. Now, since your data is already a `JSON` format (despite the quotes), one simple solution to this is by replacing the single-quotes with double-quotes, hence:

```
SELECT *,
       REPLACE(data,'\'','"') AS replaced_quotes,
       JSON_VALID(REPLACE(data,'\'','"')) AS check_if_json_data_is_valid
FROM my_test;
```

This will return the following result:

| id | data | replaced_quotes | check_if_json_data_is_valid |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | {'field1': '123432', 'field2':'TEST', 'field3': ''} | {"field1": "123432", "field2":"TEST", "field3": ""} | 1 |
| 2 | {'field1': '322345', 'field2':'TEST 2', 'field3': 'TEST'} | {"field1": "322345", "field2":"TEST 2", "field3": "TEST"} | 1 |

With single-quotes being replaced by double-quotes, `check_if_json_data_is_valid` is now returning `1`, so it's now a valid `JSON` value. What you can do next is taking the `REPLACE(data,'\'','"')` and use it for your operation:

```
SELECT *,
       JSON_UNQUOTE(JSON_EXTRACT(REPLACE(data,'\'','"'), '$.field3')) AS field3
      FROM my_test
HAVING field3 != ''
```

[Demo fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=93340d0404d7b7df3f5be45bdd0fbcb0)

As for the `INSERT` query, either you're doing it manually or generating it through code, make sure you change the single-quotes to double-quotes so that you won't need to do `REPLACE()` on `data` column anymore. And make sure to check your `JSON` value with `JSON_VALID` too.